# ImportError: cannot import name 'safe_join'

Tags: python

I want to upload my static files to AWS CloudFront through s3. 
I have this error : `ImportError: cannot import name 'safe_join'` when running `python manage.py collectstatic`

I am using Python 3.6 and Django 2x.
`django-storage-redux` is installed, `boto3` and `botocore` too.

here is my `settings.py` :

```
import os
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
import boto3

...


# AWS CloudFront
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-2'  # e.g. us-east-2
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '****'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '***'
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=1209600, no-transform'
}

# static
BUCKET_STATIC_NAME = '***'
CLOUDFRONT_STATIC_DOMAIN = '***'

# media
BUCKET_MEDIA_NAME = '***'
CLOUDFRONT_MEDIA_DOMAIN = '***'

# storage
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'elef.custom_storage.CachedStaticS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'elef.custom_storage.MediaS3BotoStorage'

MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s/' % CLOUDFRONT_MEDIA_DOMAIN

...
```

here is my `custom_storage.py` :

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
import boto3

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import CachedFilesMixin


class CachedStaticS3BotoStorage(CachedFilesMixin, S3Boto3Storage):
    """
    S3BotoStorage backend which also saves a hashed copies of the files it saves.
    """
    bucket_name = settings.BUCKET_STATIC_NAME
    custom_domain = settings.CLOUDFRONT_STATIC_DOMAIN


class MediaS3BotoStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    """
    S3BotoStorage backend for media files.
    """
    bucket_name = settings.BUCKET_MEDIA_NAME
    custom_domain = settings.CLOUDFRONT_MEDIA_DOMAIN
```

i can also give you the full traceback:

```
/Users/justine_dev/zapelef/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/__init__.py:9: UserWarning: This library has been designated as the official successor of django-storages and releases under that namespace. Please update your requirements files to point to django-storages.
  warnings.warn('This library has been designated as the official successor of django-storages and '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/justine_dev/zapelef/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/justine_dev/zapelef/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/justine_dev/zapelef/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/justine_dev/zapelef/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/justine_dev/zapelef/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 162, in handle
    if self.is_local_storage() and self.storage.location:
  File "/Users/justine_dev/zapelef/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 216, in is_local_storage
    return isinstance(self.storage, FileSystemStorage)
  File "/Users/justine_dev/zapelef/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 213, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/Users/justine_dev/zapelef/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 491, in _setup
    self._wrapped = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)()
  File "/Users/justine_dev/zapelef/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 356, in get_storage_class
    return import_string(import_path or settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE)
  File "/Users/justine_dev/zapelef/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/Users/justine_dev/zapelef/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/justine_dev/Desktop/elefmarket/elef/custom_storage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
  File "/Users/justine_dev/zapelef/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 18, in <module>
    from storages.utils import safe_join, setting
ImportError: cannot import name 'safe_join'
```

I can see in the traceback that i need to "update my requirements files to point to django-storages". i don't know what it means, and `django-storages` is also installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want to be using `django-storages-redux`, the warning is correct in telling you that you should replace it with `django-storages`. Your error was caused by having both `django-storages` and `django-storages-redux` installed at the same time. You should remove the `-redux` package, and repair your setup by re-installing `django-storages`, alone.

The warning is raised because you have version 1.3.3 of the deprecated [`django-storages-redux` project](https://pypi.org/project/django-storages-redux/) installed; this is the [only release with that warning](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/commit/4503027d1333288a844a754cbe92ce9f03bbc133#diff-7d7e96974dff6c5efdca1620cfdaba7c). Version 1.3.3 is quite old, it was released in 2017.

You need to *uninstall* that project, and then re-install `django-storages`:

```
pip uninstall django-storages-redux
pip install --force-reinstall django-storages
```

Make sure that `django-storages-redux` is not listed in your requirements.txt file or as a dependency anywhere.

The `django-storages-redux` and `django-storages` projects write to the same package, and they clashed, creating a broken package. The `storage.utils` module is [the version from `django-storages-redux`](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/4503027d1333288a844a754cbe92ce9f03bbc133/storages/utils.py), while the `storage.backends.s3boto3` module is [new in version 1.5.0 of `django-storage](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/1.5.0/CHANGELOG.rst).

Comment: Thanks! now i have an other error: `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied`. I guess it is an aws config problem, if you also have an answer for this it would be great haha! otherwise i'll ask this in a different question (all my buckets have the right permissions so i don't get it)

Comment: @justinedupuis: yes, that'd be a new question. Sorry, I don't have any recent boto config experience, I don't know why you are getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

```
from werkzeug.utils import safe_join
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Hey Benjamin no need to edit anything your answer is perfect.